# Should I encapsulate JSON data into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Assuming that you have a server-side Javascript application and you receive the following data from the client-side:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "0001",
        "Details": [
            {
                "Name": "John",
                "Surname": "Doe",
                "bankAccount": "123"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Would it be a good practice to encapsulate this data into a Javascript object? e.g.,

```
    var Person = (function () {
    var bankAccount = "";

    function Person(userId, name, surname, bankAccount) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;

        this.getBankAccount = function() {
            return this.bankAccount;
        };
        this.setBankAccount = function(ba) {
            this.bankAccount = ba;
        };
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

This way I can have control over actions involving the user's sensitive data:

```
   var p = new Person(1, "John", "doe", "123");
   p.name
=> 'John'
   p.bankAccount
   p.getBankAccount()
   p.setBankAccount(123)
   p.getBankAccount()
=> 123
```

However, if I need to persist this data to a NoSQL database like MongoDB, I would need to serialize everything back to JSON, isn't that kind of weird? I wonder what are your thoughts around this practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several advantages of encapsulating pure JavaScript Objects in some kind of interface, with mehtods that will `get` or `set` your values.

Actually there are many Frameworks that can help you with that.

#### [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
var person = new Person({id : 1, name : "Peter"});

person.get("id");
// -> 1

person.get("name");
// -> Peter
```

One advantage is that you can define your own `parsing` functions that will take the JSON from the server and transform it as you want.

Another advantage is that you can hook yourselve into the setting process using events.

```
person.on("change:name", function() { console.log("changed..."); });
person.set("name", "Frank");
// the change callback gets fired.
```

Also you can, when you need to persist your data, transform your object back to a pure JavaScript Object.

```
// in Backbone
person.toJSON();
// -> {id:1, name:"Peter"}
```

If we are talking about techniques on the **server**, there you dont need neither a framework nor getters or setters as functions, as you can define them directly using the `get` and `set` syntax

```
var log = ['test'];
var obj = {
  get latest () {
    if (log.length == 0) return undefined;
    return log[log.length - 1]
  }
}
console.log (obj.latest); // Will return "test".

var latest = obj.latest;
// works

obj.latest = "something";
// throws...
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the downvote, can you ellaborate why my answer is so wrong?

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote because I liked the Backbone method (less verbose) but I was hoping to get more comments regarding the deserialization and serialization of the JSON data to move the data around layers of the application before persisting it. thoughts?

Comment: before I update my answers, are we talking client side or server side?

Comment: server side. I was expecting some comments from RhinoJS/node.js/avatar.js programmers...